# How to fix Unity Container Warning: "ContainerElement.Configure(Unity.IUnityContainer) is obsolete"?

Tags: c#, .net, prism, unity-container

I have just installed Prism4 on my box and trying to get started working on a example of Unity (UnityContainer).

I am using SL4, Prism4, .Net Framework4, VS 2010 Ultimate.

I am getting a warning in the class `Program.cs` on line `configSection.Containers.Default.Configure(container);`

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.Configure(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer)'
>   is obsolete: '"Use the UnityConfigurationSection.Configure(container,
>   name) method instead'

This is the code that I wrote:

```
var configurationSection = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity"); 
foreach (ContainerElement containerElement in configurationSection.Containers) 
{ 
    container =configurationSection.Configure(container, containerElement.Name); 
}
```

I understand that the old method is deprecated and needs to be replaced, but how can this be done? The code I tried above seams to be not working correctly.

Comment: Ok, but what is question? The warning describes that you need to use `UnityConfigurationSection.Configure` instead...

Comment: hello, tank you for your answer. yes i did understand that and i tried it. This is the code taht i wrote: var configurationSection = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity"); foreach (ContainerElement containerElement in configurationSection.Containers) { container =configurationSection.Configure(container, containerElement.Name); } but i still get the same error.

Comment: Error or warning? In your changed code you shouldn't get the compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

A previous method in the Unity library - `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.ContainerElement.Configure(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer)` has now been replaced with a new  implementation `UnityConfigurationSection.Configure(container, name)`.

It's telling you that the original method has been replaced by a new one the new version of the Unity library so just use the new method. If you want the legacy method you will need to use an old version of the Unity library.

Comment: hello, tank you for your answer. yes i did understand that and i tried it. This is the code taht i wrote:                                                                 var configurationSection =
                (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");

            foreach (ContainerElement containerElement in configurationSection.Containers)
            {
                container =configurationSection.Configure(container, containerElement.Name);
            }                                                              but i still get the same error.

Comment: I have a similar situation with the code fragment emitting the same obsolete warning: `_iocContainer = new UnityContainer();
    var section
     = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
    section.Containers.Default.Configure(_iocContainer); ` Should I replace the second line by `section.Configure(_iocContainer, "unity");` ? This is not 100% clear for me.